# the size of dynamically allocated array in C

Tags: arrays, c, sizeof, c89, ansi-c

I know that this question has been asked before, but my question is more specific,
here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>    /* must be included for the time function */

main()
{
    time_t t = time(NULL);
    srand((unsigned) t);

    int i = rand();

    int a[i];

    printf("%d\n", i);        /* ouptut: 18659 */
    printf("%d\n", sizeof a); /* output: 74636 */
}
```

I compiled this code using gcc and -ansi option to restrict it to recognize the ANSI C only.
I know that there is no way that the compiler could know at compile-time the size of the array because it's determined randomly at run-time.
Now my question is **is the value returned by sizeof is just a random value, or it has a meaning?**

Comment: This is not valid C89 code, due to the variable-length array.  It's valid in C99+, where sizeof explicitly does runtime magic on VLAs (hint: what is 74636 / 18659 ?)

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth but why does it compile?

Comment: Lets do an exercise - we try to multiply 18659 with 4. What do we get?

Comment: If You want ANSI C only, Use with `-pedantic` option (with `-Werror`). (Turn off GCC's extensions.)

Comment: from your output obviously that `sizeof a` is real size of `int a[I]`

Comment: BTW, to avoid UB this should be `printf("%zu\n", sizeof a);`. sizeof returns a size_t, not int.

Comment: thank's for your info, it helps

Comment: Says TFM "The -ansi option does not cause non-ISO programs to be rejected gratuitously. For that, -pedantic is required in addition to -ansi".

Comment: @Jens but the _z_ option is c99 and not c89.

Comment: @MaykelJakson But variable arrays are C99 and not C89. You can't have it both ways. And even in C89, a size_t is not an int, and as such you have UB.

Comment: @Jens indeed, I didn't know that, because **gcc file.c -ansi** didn't complain, but I knew later that I had to add another option **-pedantic** if I _'realy'_ wanted gcc to compile c89 code only.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value returned by `sizeof` is a pseudo-random value that has a meaning:

- The value represents the size of VLA `a`, in bytes
- It is random only in the sense that the number of array elements is determined by a call to `rand`.

It appears that `sizeof(int)` on your system is 4, because the number returned by `sizeof` is four times the number of elements in the array.

**Note:** One of the consequences of allowing VLAs in C99 is that `sizeof` is no longer a purely compile-time expression. When the argument of `sizeof` operator is a VLA, the result is computed at run-time.

Answer (score 6):

The `sizeof` operator is evaluated at compile time for most operands.  In the case of a VLA, it is evaluated at runtime.

From section 6.5.3.4 of the [C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf):

> *2* **The `sizeof` operator yields the size (in bytes) of its operand**, which may be an expression or the parenthesized name of a type. The
>   size is determined from the type of the operand. The result is an
>   integer. **If the type of the operand is a variable length array type,
>   the operand is evaluated; otherwise, the operand is not evaluated and
>   the result is an integer constant**

So the size returned by `sizeof` is the size in bytes of the VLA.  In your example, that would be `i * sizeof(int)`

Answer (score 2):

> is the value returned by sizeof is just a random value, or it has a meaning?

It does have a meaning, as `74636` / `18659` = `4`, which apparently is the size of `int` on your machine.

So `sizeof` (which will be computed at run-time instead of compile-time since the argument is a VLA), will return the size of array `a` in bytes, which is the number of `int`s it contains (in other words `i` or `18659`) multiplied by the size of `int`, which is `4` on your machine.

As `i` (the result of `rand`) is random, you can consider that the value of `sizeof` will be random too in that sense.

Answer (score 2):

From the [gcc manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Dialect-Options.html#C-Dialect-Options)

> The -ansi option does not cause non-ISO programs to be rejected gratuitously. For that, -Wpedantic is required in addition to -ansi.

Comment: That is not really the answer to the question (sizeof(a) valid for VLA), is it?

Comment: @Aconcagua actually it is, because it means that sizeof(a) is no more evaluated in compile time only as it is the case in C89 (not using -Wpedantic option).

Comment: @MaykelJakson The word 'sizeof' is not even mentioned in the answer - neither any word about evaluating it at compile/run time, neither a confirmation that the struct is valid. *This* would have been what makes the right answer - given one answers the question "How to compile ANSI only with GCC?", which OP (incorrectly) assumed already being doing...